# MYSQL select by URL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a table looks like this:

```
id    url                                         title
1     http://afef.com/abc/def/gje/qkd             hello
2     http://afe.com/?a=3&b=2&fse=3               hello
3     http://stackoverflow.com/fefw/sefac/fsg     hello-world
```

from here `id` is primary key and auto_increment, and `url` is unique, but `title` can be duplicated.

From this point of view, when I add new URL to this table, like :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (url, title)
VALUES ('http://abcd.com/affefef/sfsaa/?a=3', 'this is title')
```

Then, if it is new URL to insert, it doesn't matter. But if it is duplicated URL, it will be ignored and I can't know what the duplicated URL's `id` is.

The `id` must not be changed.

Is there any solutions to know `id` when I INSERT duplicated URL with one query ?

Comment: Before inserting, you can check if that URL exist or not using select query .

Comment: you can use `select insert`

Comment: @zan Isn't it not too long to compare very long url?? I mean if I use `select` it will compare all rows with very long url.

Comment: yeah , but leave that operation on Mysql.

Comment: I think mongodb can easily get your inserted id, or you just add a validator in to your mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditionally checking would help in getting duplicate ID

Check this code:

```
 mysql.query("SELECT id FROM table  WHERE url = 'http://abcd.com/affefef/sfsaa/?a=3", function(error, result, field) {
            if(error) {
                exist(error); //No error
            } else if (result) {
                if (result.length > 0){
                    console.log("Id exist:" + result['id']);
                }else{

                // write your insert statement here
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yeah my bad , I am a PHP Freak right now , I will change it to node version , thanks for pointing out @NewbeeDev

Answer (score 1):

In one query only, I think it's not possible. But you can use the Mysql function "last_insert_id" to retrieve the id which has been inserted. Checking it, you would be able to see if it's a new one or not.
See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-last_insert_id.aspx

You can also have a look at "insert on duplicate". With this syntax it will update the field if it exists or inserts a new one if the key isn't found.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html